# Two ViewPagers from one PagerTitleStrip.

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have two ViewPagers with the a PagerTitleStrip in the center of them. What I want to be able to do is to Scroll One of the ViewPagers and this will be mirrored in the top one at exactly the same time. Anybody got any ideas how I would go about this?

The code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager2" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/meatb"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="9dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only just realised this question was still unanswered but here's how I got it working:

```
 mViewPager2.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            mViewPager.scrollTo(arg0*width + arg2, 0);
            currentPos = arg0;
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPos,false);
        }
    });

    mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: well, that's exactly what I suggested, You could have just accepted my answer ;-)

Comment: Not really, the important part is to change the currentpos variable when you change a page and otherwise to monitor monitor onPageScrolled for changes.

Comment: This is taken care of in mPager2.setCurrentItem(mPage1.getCurrentItem())

Comment: I didn't fully read your code - if scrollTo moves the page to pixel location, than you've found the link I was missing. nice!

Comment: Yep it does. And I'm glad I could help really! (The amount of time I spent on this for such a relatively simple piece of code is quite something!)

Comment: Oh and for people wondering, width is the width of the ViewPager. (Which in my case is the width of the screen)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to set a "mid position" for a pager, so it doesn't seem possible to set it while receiving `onDrag` events.

A partial solution, though, would be to add a scroll listener to one `mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(..)`

and trigger a page transition on the other when that happens: `mPager2.setCurrentItem(mPage1.getCurrentItem())`
.

It's partial solution since it won't be simultaneous, since the event will (probably) be triggered when the page was already scrolled.

If you must have this happen simultaneously, than you'll need a view that you can control its drawing or view positioning to the pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've got it working now. I'll give you a vote up anyway.